# Hibernate: Relation with @Filter, @JoinTable and InheritanceType.JOINED throws Exception: "missing FROM-clause entry"

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

### Problem

Hibernate seems to generate an invalid PSQL query if a @Filter condition references a field of an inherited superclass.

### Details

I have a ManyToMany relation between class OwnerGroup and class OwnerGroupsInvoiceParty. A @Filter is defined on the relation, which removes soft-deleted values of OwnerGroupsInvoiceParty. The soft-deletion field deletedAt is not defined on OwnerGroupsInvoiceParty, but on a superclass AbstractInvoiceParty (InheritanceType.JOINED).

If I now activate the filter (session.enableFilter("filterDeleted")) and call ownerGroup.getPartyOnInvoices(), a PSQLException is thrown:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "ownergroup1_1_"

My class definitions:

```
@Entity
public class OwnerGroup {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "ownerGroups")
    @Filter(name = "filterDeleted", condition = "{s}.deleted_at IS NULL", aliases = {
        @org.hibernate.annotations.SqlFragmentAlias(alias = "s", table = "abstract_invoice_party") 
    })
    protected Set<OwnerGroupsInvoiceParty> partyOnInvoices = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<OwnerGroupsInvoiceParty> getPartyOnInvoices() {
       return this.partyOnInvoices;
    }
}

@Entity
public class OwnerGroupsInvoiceParty extends AbstractInvoiceParty {

   @JoinTable
   @ManyToMany
   protected Set<OwnerGroup> ownerGroups = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class AbstractInvoiceParty {
    
    protected Date deletedAt = null;

}
```

I have looked at the generated plain SQL query and there the error becomes clear ([Image of query with highlighted error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYNC8.png)):

```
SELECT partyoninv0_.owner_groups_id  as owner_gr2_267_0_,
   partyoninv0_.party_on_invoices_id as party_on1_267_0_,
   ownergroup1_.id                   as id2_21_1_,
   ownergroup1_1_.deleted_at         as deleted_3_21_1_ 
FROM 
   owner_groups_invoice_party_owner_groups partyoninv0_ 
INNER JOIN 
   owner_groups_invoice_party ownergroup1_ 
     ON partyoninv0_.party_on_invoices_id = ownergroup1_.id 
     AND ownergroup1_1_.deleted_at IS NULL 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   abstract_invoice_party ownergroup1_1_ 
     ON ownergroup1_.id = ownergroup1_1_.id 
WHERE partyoninv0_.owner_groups_id=?
```

Hibernate Version: 5.6.9

Is there a way to define the filter so that a correct query is generated?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, which you should report in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Hey Christian, 
thanks for the advice, I'll do so.